# Does armeabi-v7a-hard enable NEON in android NDK r10c?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

according to NDK documentation, `armeabi-v7a-hard` ABI should be the same as `armeabi-v7a`, except it adds following flags to compilation:

```
TARGET_CFLAGS += -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1
TARGET_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-warn-mismatch -lm_hard
```

However, I've noticed that library built in `armeabi-v7a-hard` mode has enabled NEON and does not work on Tegra2 tablet (app receives SIGILL as soon as native library is loaded):

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -A libRecognizer.so 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM v7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

`ndk-build -n` shows that NEON should not be enabled for compilation:

```
-fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64
```

Is this expected? Is NEON enabled automatically by GCC when hard float is used?

I've build the same library in `armeabi-v7a` mode, `ndk-build -n` shows following compilation flags:

```
-fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64
```

Binary then works on Tegra2 tablet and readelf outputs the following:

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -A libBlinkRecognizer.so 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM v7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

Is it possible to use hardfloat ABI without NEON?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: In our products we dropped support for Tegra 2 devices so this is not an issue for us anymore. However, if this is still happening with r11c and r12 beta, please file a report [here](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues). The NDK devs are very active in resolving issues on their new issue tracker on Github.